# How to insert a .zip file into a MySQL database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell, zip, sql-insert

I have a MySQL database and I need to use Windows Powershell to insert a `.zip` file of 90KB into a table.

What SQL command should I use for it? How can I do it?

Comment: Why you need to insert your file into a database? Just store the file path or name, when you need it, app(Python, php code, etc...) read the database to get where the file is and read/write the file.

Comment: Is it the contents of the ZIP you need to insert? Is there some kind of file inside with the values for various fields that you need to insert?

Answer (score 1):

The `.zip` file should contain a `.sql` file, which can be imported using the following commands:

#### CMD

```
mysql -p -u[database_user] [database] < C:/path/to/file.sql
```

#### Powershell

```
cmd.exe /c "mysql -p -u[database_user] [database] < C:/path/to/file.sql"
```